# Cannot apply additional policy bindings to existing bucket in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, policy, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to grant additional IAM permissions to an existing bucket, such that the user will be able to list, view and see IAM permissions on a particular bucket,

PS : email is replaced by a valid email address of the user who has access to the bucket-name (valid bucket)

I am trying to grant additional IAM permissions to an existing bucket, such that user will be able to list, view and see IAM policy on a particular bucket,

PS : email is replaced by a valid email address of the user who has access to the bucket-name (valid bucket)

```
$ gcloud storage buckets add-iam-policy-binding gs://bucket-name --member=user:email --role=roles/storage.bucket.get
```

And

```
gcloud storage buckets add-iam-policy-binding gs://bucket-name --member=user:emailo --role=roles/storage.buckets.getIamPolicy
```

However, I am receiving the following error below for both commands executed above,

`ERROR: (gcloud.storage.buckets.add-iam-policy-binding) HTTPError 400: Role roles/storage.bucket.get is not supported for this resource.`

Comment: Where are you getting those IAM role names from? Neither one exists. Are you confusing role names and permission names?

Comment: John is right, you mixed role and permission. If you want to grant a single one permission, you can create a custom role.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your responses John Hanley, Guillaume Blaquiere.

The answer I was/am looking for is/was,

**IAM permissions:**

1. resourcemanager.folders.get

2. resourcemanager.folders.list

3. resourcemanager.organizations.get

4. resourcemanager.projects.get

5. resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy

6. resourcemanager.projects.list

7. resourcemanager.organizations.setIamPolicy

8. storage.buckets.get

Comment: Do not use comments to add details, edit your post.